# How do I prevent auto video play on web sites on iPhone 6s?

Tags: iphone, safari, video

Following the instruction here -- https://www.alphr.com/how-to-stop-autoplay-videos-safari/, I have disabled the "Audio Play Video Previews" setting

...

[image]

but when I visit certain web sites (cbssports.com is the example in the screen shot below),

[image]

the video starts automatically.  I have tried restarting the phone but to no avail.  The video plays and my battery drains quite rapidly.  Also the phone starts to heat up and feels very hot.

Any ideas how I can disable auto video play on the iPhone for Safari?

Comment: This isn't strictly answering your question, but you mentioned battery drain as a side effect, so I thought I'd ask: have you considered replacing your phone's battery? If this phone has been in use for a few years, a battery replacement could make a big difference. It takes about an hour and it should be a painless process, and for pre-2017 phones, it only costs $50.

Comment: You could try to use an AdBlocker, as this (autoplay video even when disabled) is a bad practice established by companies on the web just like auto link clicking.